# G++: Linking a dynamic (dylib) library

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, dylib

I've been recently trying to write an opengl program on Mac and deploy it as a console application and distribute it to other Mac users.

Since the program is written in C++, I decided to use g++. My program requires the use of the OpenGL framework, GLFW, and GLEW. I have the GLFW and GLEW libraries in my /usr/local/lib folder and the header files in my /usr/local/include folder. My main file is called main.cpp. The GLFW dynamic loading library is called libglfw.3.2.dylib and the GLEW dynamic loading library is called libGLEW.2.0.0.dylib.

When I compile in g++ using the following command from the directory of the main.cpp file:

```
g++ -arch x86_64 -framework OpenGL -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib  -o Main main.cpp -lglfw.3.2 -lGLEW.2.0.0
```

Everything compiles correctly and the program runs.

However, this links the libraries through an absolute path: /usr/local/lib. This means that when I move my executable to another computer, it won't run. I need the dylibs to load on every computer. So I tried moving them to the folder that has my main.cpp file and using `$(CURDIR)` to link to my current directory:

```
g++ -arch x86_64 -framework OpenGL -I/usr/local/include -L'$(CURDIR)'  -o Main main.cpp -lglfw.3.2 -lGLEW.2.0.0
```

This doesn't work since for some reason it doesn't seem to recognize '$(CURDIR)' as the current directory or maybe it isn't a valid variable to use.

I'm looking for a way to link my dylibs so that I can move my executable to any computer and have it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: It simply doesn't recognize the path as the current directory's path.

Comment: Not sure really, but try removing the quotes from -L'$(CURDIR)'. On my MSYS shell (on Windows), if I leave the quotes, it seems to not expand the variable (at least with echo). Also try removing the parenthesis.

Comment: I tried that but it said -L$CURDIR isn't recognized as a path either

Answer (score 1):

The path given with `-L` is just for the linker to find *extra* libraries. Where these libraries are located at runtime is not controlled with `-L`. Instead you should look at something called `rpath`. There's an article on how to do it properly on MacOS X: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html

Comment: I tried the following: g++ -arch x86_64 -framework OpenGL -I/usr/local/include -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'  -o Main main.cpp libglfw.3.2.dylib libGLEW.2.0.0.dylib. It compiled properly but as soon as I moved the folder to another mac, I got the same problem as before.

Comment: @OrrenRavid: Please read the link I gave in the answer. rpaths work different in MacOS (Apple suffers strongly from NIH) and don't use the `$ORIGIN` variable, but expand the `@rpath` macro.

Comment: There is no explanation on how to use it in a compiler, it only explains that there exists an @rpath macro that uses relative paths but it never explains how to use it.

Comment: @OrrenRavid: On the page I linked it's clearly stated: *"To create a run-path dependent library, you specify a run-path–relative pathname as the library’s install name. (…) A run-path install name is an install name that uses a run-path–relative pathname. You specify a run-path install name while creating the dependent library using the gcc `-install_name` option. See the gcc man page for more information."*

Comment: The thing is, these dependent libraries have already been made, I don't compile them myself. So if that's true, how do I modify it so that the install name is relative to my executable. Now I have found a few solutions online, but none have been very specific to my problem which is why I decided to post it here. I clearly stated in my question that I had already precompiled these libraries meaning I don't compile them through g++.

Comment: @OrrenRavid: What's stopping you from building GLFW yourself? BTW: unless you're using some of the obscure Apple specific OpenGL extensions there zero need for GLEW. In MacOS X the OpenGL framework delivers all functions, also from modern OpenGL profiles and GLEW adds nothing to your program (except loading of some extensions made by Apple which hardly anybody uses). In fact it is a totally viable approach to just statically link GLFW and be done with it.

Comment: That may be true, an I appreciate the suggestion. However that isn't topical to my request. I fear this dylib thing may continue to haunt me throughout my programming career with programming in MacOS X and therefore I would like a way to correclty do this in this exact way. Now the glew thing is just added for completness' sake as I am also programming the game for Windows which requires GLEW. I tried statically linking GLFW as a .a file and received a bunch of errors that I didn't receive when I linked the dylibs which is why I decided to do it with dylibs.